# ReferenceError: event is not defined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am using this function:

```
$("#tooltip").animate({ left: event.clientX, top: event.clientY });
```

Its working on Chrome and IE but in Firefox I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined $("#tooltip").animate({ left:
event.clientX, top: event.clientY });
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Can you please post the function in which you call animate.

Answer (score 6):

You appear to be trying to use the odd global event object that is a legacy of the 4.0-browser-era Microsoft event model. Don't. Use the standard event object instead. It will be the first argument to your event handler function.

```
jQuery('selector').on('click', function (evt) {
    jQuery("#tooltip").animate({ left: evt.clientX, top: evt.clientY });
});
```

Comment: @mothana it should work. You are doing something wrong somewhere in your 'not posted' code

Answer (score 2):

Mothana, Quentin is right,almost. I work with d3.js (jQuery like library) and the old story browser thing is that events that are not declared are not acceptable. So you have 3 weays to solve this:

**1. Don't use events** - not our case i think.

**2. Use the standard event object of your function** - Example in Quentin's answer.

**3. Make your javascript library object do the work for you.**
Example in d3.js:
I had this not working code:

```
    tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px"))
```

and i used the d3.js object named "d3" to make the selection of the event for me (working code):

```
tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px")
```

So I suppose in jQuery you must use the name of your javascript library object, something like jQuery.someSelection().