# jQuery AJAX dataType: 'script' not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, firefox

I have this code for my form in jQuery:

```
$('form.ajax_form').on('submit', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_errors_space = $(this).find('.ajax_form_errors:first');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'script',
      url: $(this).attr('action'), 
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      // show success response from server.
      success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(jqXHR);
      },
      // show error response from the server.
      error: function(data, status, error_message) {
       // error handeling here
      }
    });
  });
```

Code works for chrome and safari. Issue is with Firefox, which sends the AJAX request as 'HTML' data type instead of JS/script. Any idea?

Note: I am doing this on Ruby on Rails 4, Ruby 2.1.1, I can't use default `remote: true` option for project specific reasons.

Firefox version: 30.0

**UPDATE: ** I tried to override content type and MIME type as well, and it didn't work either.

```
  ...
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  contentType: 'application/javascript',
  accepts: 'text/script',
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "application/script; charset=x-user-defined" );
  },
  .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to as shown below:

```
$('form.ajax_form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
```

instead of:

```
$('form.ajax_form').on('submit', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
```

more [information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18810905/3681493)

Comment: woooohooooo!! This works, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 'text' instead of script:

```
$('form.ajax_form').on('submit', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_errors_space = $(this).find('.ajax_form_errors:first');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'text',
      url: $(this).attr('action'), 
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      // show success response from server.
      success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(jqXHR);
      },
      // show error response from the server.
      error: function(data, status, error_message) {
       // error handeling here
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Tried 'text', too. But, it doesn't work for all the browsers then. Because, it sends the format as: 'TEXT'. I need to send request as 'JS' and hence 'script'.

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer. I've got the solution.